# When conducting an heuristic evaluation, do you also make note of conforming elements?

Tags: usability, usability-study, heuristics

When conducting an heuristic evaluation, do you you also make note of the elements that conform, or do you only look for elements that do not conform to the heuristics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of a heuristic evaluation is to find problems with the current design. It is usually accomplished with some kind of a rubric, so you need to mark elements as Pass/Fail or give them a score while providing an explanation for fails and low scores. If you're working without a rubric (such as checking specifically the flow or microcopy), you need to point out only the problem areas.

Heuristic evaluations have nothing to do with commending the design team - that's what stakeholders, users, and AIGA/IxDA/etc do. If you see a unique cool interaction, you can comment privately but it shouldn't be included in the report.